# migration of irregular polygons to grids/blocks

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

How do you convert irregular polygons to grids (blocks) of regular/square shapes. I am trying to convert irregular shaped mining concessions to regular blocks in ArcGIS

Am using arcgis 10, arcinfo
I have created square grids of 45seconds for the whole country. Now I want to make sure all irregularly shaped mining concessions are converted to match the grids. Obviously a concession will lose/gain some areas.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include what version of ArcGIS you are using and also which license you have?

Comment: I don't think "migration" is the correct term to use here - it sounds to me like you want to snap your irregular polygons to a fishnet (of 45 seconds square).

Comment: Its true I want to snap the irregular polygons to the fishnet. If the centroids of the 45 sec squares fall within the irregular polygon, then the irregular polygon should snap to all those squares

Comment: Would a spatial join suit your needs? You could convert your irregular polygons to centroids or points, join them to the fishnet, and then export out only the matched features. If you choose to convert your polygons to points, in the end you could dissolve each collection of fishnet blocks that represent one feature.

Comment: you could also directly convert your polygons to raster. But your question needs to specify the rule to apply when more than one concession falls in one square.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your polygons to rasters using "[polygon to raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000030000000)" with the cell size of 45 seconds. In order to get it to line up properly with your data you will need to use a "[snap raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w0000000m000000)" with an origin on the grid line, something with a world file and manually edit the value so that it lines up.

Convert the raster to polygons without the "simplify polygons" option which will give regular polygons based on the cells. Tool "[Raster to Polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000008000000)".

Perform a spatial join of the original polygons to the regular polygons to permanently join the attributes.

Warning: This will destroy polygons that are less than half the size of a grid cell.